# Regular expression to match exact 11 digits numbers

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match exact 11 digits(no spaces, no alphabets). Valid values are

1. 12345678987 - Valid
2. 123456789876 - not valid because it has more than 11 digits
3. 1234 5678987 - Not valid (since it has space)
4. 11223344556 - valid
5. A1234B5678987 - not valid (because it has alphabets)

I tried the below expression but no luck
var aa = new RegExp("^[0-9]{11});
var bb = new RegExp("/d{11});( this will give valid to even 1,2,3,4)

Comment: Your last paragraph has several syntax errors (non-matched quotes) and a wrong slash in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [start and end](https://regex101.com/r/UF9dpn/1) of string

```
^\d{11}$
```

```js
const str = `12345678987
123456789876
1234 5678987
11223344556
A1234B5678987`;

console.log(str.match(/^\d{11}$/gm))
```

or using a [Word Boundary](https://regex101.com/r/UF9dpn/2):

```
\b\d{11}\b
```